# Default culture in URL routing during localization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, localization, globalization

I recently took over a huge C# MVC project. It's localized to English and Norwegian, but I'm having some issues with the localization and how to set the route correctly. What I want to achieve is the following:

1. /controller/action --> should map to the default language (Norwegian)
2. /no/controller/action --> should map to the page in Norwegian
3. /en/controller/action --> should map to the page in English

For all cases, the URL should stay the same. Do I need to set up a separate non-localized route for all cases, like I've done for the login-page? Here's the main part of the code:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "metaRelated",
            url: "related/{type}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Meta", action = "Related" }
        ).RouteHandler = new MultiCultureMvcRouteHandler();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "login",
            url: "Login",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login" }
        ).RouteHandler = new MultiCultureMvcRouteHandler();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "loginNoCulture",
            url: "Login",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", culture = UrlParameter.Optional }
        ).RouteHandler = new MvcRouteHandler();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "actionStatus",
            url: "DocumentActions/{ActionStatus}/{DocumentId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Action", action = "Index", DocumentId = UrlParameter.Optional }
        ).RouteHandler = new MultiCultureMvcRouteHandler();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        ).RouteHandler = new MultiCultureMvcRouteHandler();


        foreach (Route r in routes)
        {
            if (r.RouteHandler is MultiCultureMvcRouteHandler)
            {
                r.RouteHandler = new MultiCultureMvcRouteHandler();
                r.Url = "{culture}/" + r.Url;

                // Adding default culture 
                if (r.Defaults == null)
                    r.Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary();

                r.Defaults.Add("culture", Culture.No.ToString().ToLower());

                // Adding constraint for culture param
                if (r.Constraints == null)
                    r.Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary();

                r.Constraints.Add("culture", new CultureConstraint(Culture.En.ToString().ToLower(), Culture.No.ToString().ToLower(), Culture.Nl.ToString().ToLower()));
            }
        }
```

Here's the MultiCultureMvcRouteHandler class:

```
public class MultiCultureMvcRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
    {
        protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            var culture = requestContext.RouteData.Values["culture"].ToString();
            var ci = new CultureInfo(culture);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
            return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `MultiCultureMvcRouteHandler` seem to be some sort of custom class... You may want to re-read [MCVE] guidance and than [edit] post accordingly...

Comment: shouldn't this code be placed in your controller instead of the route file.. also yes it seems a lot of the code is hidden because of the custom class

Comment: I added the code for MultiCultureMvcRouteHandler, as requested.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into needing to do this as well.  My use case was for a Web API .NET 5.

After exploring options (aka beating head on keyboard for several days) I found a nice solution. I impliented an action filter at the global level.

Here is the ActionFilter Class

```
/// <summary>
/// This filter sets the Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture To the culture property of the route. 
/// </summary>
public class CultureActionFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{   
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        try
        {
            if (context.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("culture"))
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(context.RouteData.Values["culture"].ToString());
        }
        catch { }

        await next();
    }
}
```

As you can see it is pretty simple.  It looks to see if culture is in the route data then will try to parse it and set the current thread culture.

In Configure Services

```
services.AddControllers(config => config.Filters.Add(new CultureActionFilter()));

 services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(new CultureInfo("en-US-POSIX"), new CultureInfo("en-US"));
            options.SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>(_allowedCultures);
            options.SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>(_allowedCultures);                
            options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider());
            services.AddSingleton(options);
        });

        services.AddRouting(options =>
        {
            options.LowercaseUrls = true;
        });
```

Then in Configure

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();                                
        });
```

Now you can test it out in a controller add the {culture} to the route.
Example

```
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/{culture}/[controller]/[action]")]
```

Then you can use it like this in a method.

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        return Ok(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.EnglishName);
    }
```

Call like this
http://localhost:41121/v1/fr-CA/maintenance/test

Returns
French (Canada)